# Display objects related current user django admin

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to display only objects related to the current user. Users can upload a file and then they can only see their files in the admin. Here is my models :

```
class Share(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, default='')
    title = models.CharField("File's title", max_length=100, unique=True, default='File')
    zip_file = models.FileField('Shared File', upload_to=content_zip_name, validators= [validation_zip])
```

and my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from share.models import Share

class ShareAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title',)
    save_as = True

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ShareAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(owner=request.user)

admin.site.register(Share, ShareAdmin)
```

I tried with overriding the queryset function but doesn't work..any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused the [`queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) method  (used with `list_filter`)  with the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method:

> The `get_queryset` method on a `ModelAdmin` returns a *QuerySet* of all
>   model instances that can be edited by the admin site. One use case for
>   overriding this method is to show objects owned by the **logged-in**
>   user.

[*Emphasis mine*]

```
class ShareAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title',)
    save_as = True

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ShareAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(owner=request.user)
```

Comment: It works fine! Thanks a lot! However, when a user create an object it can select the user (because of the FK). How can I only show the current user?